# didn't work exit pop up backbutton code

Tags: android, popup, back-button, exit-code

i want to display pop up when user press back button on home screen . but it is not working,and give no error. and i work on slider menu with this code

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

    AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    build.setTitle("Confirmation");
    Log.d("aaaaa", "msg");
    build.setMessage("Are you sure, you want to exit ?");
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = build.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    build.setPositiveButton("Ha (Yes)", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    build.setNegativeButton("Na (No)", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you show the dialog before you set the yes/no buttons. You need to put alertDialog.show(); at the end. Also get rid of super.backPressed(). You do not need it since you are override this original functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `super.onBackPressed()` means "treat the back button normally" (i.e., finish the activity).

Not calling it if you want to intercept it and show a dialog (as is the case) should be enough.

Comment: ya it's work but did't show yes/no option, it's show only MSg.